# How can the Linux kernel address from 8 MB to 1 GB of virtual memory in x86 systems

Tags: linux, kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I'm studying how to enable paging in Linux kernel but I didn't understand how the kernel can address from 8 MB to 1 GB of virtual memory.
I mean, in the boot phase the kernel comes with a very minimal page table encoded into the image. This page table (pointed by swapper_pg_dir) allows you to write only the first two entries of the page table. Each entry points to a page of 4 MB. So in total the kernel can address only 8 MB of virtual memory.
Then the kernel has to instore the second level of the page table in order to drive all its 1 GB of virtual memory. In order to resolve that, it must rely in some memory allocator which allow to retrieve buffers where to put the entries of the second level page table: this is the bootmem allocator.

So my question is: how can the kernel address from 8 MB to 1 GB of virtual memory?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the question is really - it's done using the paging unit - maybe see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18431261/how-does-x86-paging-work

The page directory below 896MB is still stored in `swapper_pg_dir`, it just gets reinitialized after that first 8MB initialization. Things get more complicated above 896MB and below 4096MB, and get further complicated above 4096MB.